# How does the aggregation function work with group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I do not understand the following (returns numbers of comments for articles with the newest ones dates):

```
SELECT `id_comment`,COUNT(*) AS `number`, MAX(`date`) AS `newest` 
FROM `page_comments`  
WHERE TO_DAYS( NOW() )-TO_DAYS(`date`) < 90
GROUP BY `id_comment`
ORDER BY `count` DESC,`newest` DESC
```

I dont understand how come that the MAX function will not return the MAX value of all the page_comments table? That it automatically takes only the max for the given group. When using MAX, I would expect it to return the highest value of the column. I dont understand how it works together with groupig.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want to have the max value of the whole column, then don't use group by. Simple as that. With group by you get of course the max value of each group. And btw, it would make more sense to select `id_clanek` instead of `id_comment`, since you're grouping by `id_clanek`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just explaining it to the ground.

**MAX()** - An aggregate function(Works over the group of data).

If **""group by""** clause is **NOT** specified, the database implicitly groups the data(column specified) considering the entire result set as group.

If specified, it just groups the data(column) in the group logic specified.

Comment: also if the group by is specified, it works separately with eaah group? As I have not been able to read anything like that anywhere

Comment: group by over a column. generates a distinct key of the column, and for the evry key (group), MAX() result will be produced.

Answer (score 1):

You described the behavior yourself quite correctly already: `it automatically takes only the max for the given group`.

If you group, you do it (per usual) on every column in the result set, that is not aggregated (not using `COUNT`, `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`...)

That way you get distinct values for all non aggregated columns and the aggregated ones will yield a result that only takes the 'current' group into account.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it works like that, I just do not understand why :)I discovered accidentally :] I dont understand the "current group".

Comment: @KhDonen well the why is quite easy, you would have to write seperate queries otherwise and `union` them to get the same result, if you would want the ' total' `MAX` or something like that you simply do not group

Comment: No, I mean I do not see the logic behind by which these separated groups are being taken separately and thus max is counted for each of them.

Comment: @KhDonen the logic behind this is the distinctiveness of each row not taking into account the aggregated values: each row in the result set containing a distinct set of all columns without the aggregated ones will result in one group (but only if `group by` was specified ofc)

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to analysis order:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
   10 ORDER BY
10. TOP

so you first have the `from` clause

Then you cut the relevant rows via `where` ( so here your sentence :   *I don't understand how come that the MAX function will not return the MAX value of all the page_comments*  --fails)

then `group` it

Then you select it.

The `max` and  aggregate functions apply on the data which is already filtered!